# Iterate over list of dictionaries. Pass into function

Tags: python, parameter-passing, keyword-argument

Disclaimer. I am new to python and trying to learn. I have a list of dictionaries containing address information I would like to iterate over and then pass into a function as arguments.

`print(data)`

`[{'firstName': 'John', 'lastName': 'Smith', 'address': '123 Lane', 'country': 'United States', 'state': 'TX', 'city': 'Springfield', 'zip': '12345'}, {'firstName': 'Mary', 'lastName': 'Smith', 'address': '321 Lanet', 'country': 'United States', 'state': 'Washington', 'city': 'Springfield', 'zip': '54321'}]`

I iterate over the list and attempt pass in the values, but the values are past as a list instead of individually. I'm not sure how to correct. I'm still grasping arguments and keyword arguments. Any help and guidance is appreciated.

```
from usps import USPSApi, Address

input_name = [li['lastName'] for li in data]
input_address = [li['address'] for li in data]
input_city = [li['city'] for li in data]        
input_state = [li['state'] for li in data]        
input_zip = [li['zip'] for li in data]        
input_country = [li['country'] for li in data]  

address = Address(
    name = input_name,
    address_1= input_address,
    city= input_city,
    state=input_state,
    zipcode=input_zip
)
usps = USPSApi('------', test=True)
validation = usps.validate_address(address)
data_results = validation.result 
print(data_results)
```

Comment: Please repeat the intro tour, especially [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Your posted code fails at the first active line because `data` is undefined.  We also expect you to do your basic debugging: if you `print` your variables as you gather them, you'll see that you specifically made a full list of each portion of the address.  I'm not sure what you think `Address` is supposed to do for you, but you very clearly assigned the entire list of each portion to each field of the address.

Comment: You seem to be looking for tutorial help that is available (in pieces) in existing educational materials.  Stack Overflow is not intended to replace those resources.

Comment: do you control the upstream process that produces that list of dictionaries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have all the logic to process a *single* data point, just expand it to *multiple* data points as shown below using a loop.

```
from usps import USPSApi, Address

for item in data:
    kwargs = dict()

    kwargs['name'] = item['lastName']
    kwargs['address_1'] = item['address']
    kwargs['city'] = item['city']
    kwargs['state'] = item['state']
    kwargs['zipcode'] = item['zip']

    address = Address(**kwargs)

    usps = USPSApi('------', test=True)
    validation = usps.validate_address(address)
    data_results = validation.result 
    print(data_results)
```

Without syntactic sugar it becomes

```
for item in data:
    kwargs = dict()

    name = item['lastName']
    address_ = item['address']
    city = item['city']
    state = item['state']
    zip_ = item['zip']

    address = Address(
        name=name,
        address_1=address_,
        city=city,
        state=state,
        zipcode=zip_)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the intention is to get the key's values in a variable:

```
d_data = [{'firstName': 'John', 'lastName': 'Smith', 'address': '123 Lane', 'country': 'United States', 'state': 'TX', 'city': 'Springfield', 'zip': '12345'}, {'firstName': 'Mary', 'lastName': 'Smith', 'address': '321 Lanet', 'country': 'United States', 'state': 'Washington', 'city': 'Springfield', 'zip': '54321'}]


input_name = d_data[0]['lastName']
input_address = d_data[0]['address']
input_city = d_data[0]['city']        
input_state = d_data[0]['state']        
input_zip = d_data[0]['zip']        
input_country = d_data[0]['country']

print(input_name)
print(input_address)
print(input_city)
print(input_zip)
print(input_country)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
John                                                                                                                          
Smith                                                                                                                         
123 Lane                                                                                                                      
Springfield                                                                                                                   
12345                                                                                                                         
United States
```